Shallow better than wide deep learning embedding models?
I'm training a two-tower recommender embedding model where one tower represents users and another represents items. User and item embeddings should be close when a user clicked an item and far part otherwise. I generated a small amount of synthetic data to find any model design issues before moving on to the much larger, real dataset. However, I noticed something strange. The model seems to perform considerably worse on the training dataset when I add more layers compared to when I use a shallow network with only an embedding layer.
I'm well aware that adding more layers will often cause overfitting and worse performance on validation and test sets, but I expect the opposite on the training dataset. Adding more layers should allow the model to memorize the training data. On my real dataset, I need to be able to add more layers because of the size and complexity of my data. If I can't get my model to work on a trivial case, I certainly won't get it to perform well when I require more complexity. Am I doing something incorrectly with the additional layers that I've configured in the example code below?
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn, optim


# Configuration for synthetic data
num_clusters = 16
users_per_cluster = 50
items_per_cluster = 50
embedding_dim = 16

# Calculate total users and items
num_users = num_clusters * users_per_cluster
num_items = num_clusters * items_per_cluster

# Create user-item interaction matrix
interactions = np.zeros((num_users, num_items))
for cluster in range(num_clusters):
    user_start = cluster * users_per_cluster
    user_end = user_start + users_per_cluster
    item_start = cluster * items_per_cluster
    item_end = item_start + items_per_cluster
    interactions[user_start:user_end, item_start:item_end] = 1

# Prepare data for training
positive_pairs = []
negative_pairs = []

for user in range(num_users):
    for item in range(num_items):
        if interactions[user, item] == 1:
            positive_pairs.append((user, item, 1))
        else:
            negative_pairs.append((user, item, -1))

# Sample negatives to balance the dataset
np.random.shuffle(negative_pairs)
negative_pairs = negative_pairs[:len(positive_pairs)]
pairs = positive_pairs + negative_pairs
np.random.shuffle(pairs)

# Convert pairs to tensors
user_tensor = torch.tensor([pair[0] for pair in pairs], dtype=torch.long)
item_tensor = torch.tensor([pair[1] for pair in pairs], dtype=torch.long)
label_tensor = torch.tensor([pair[2] for pair in pairs], dtype=torch.float)


class ShallowModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_users, num_items, embedding_dim):
        super(ShallowModel, self).__init__()
        self.user_embedding = nn.Embedding(num_users, embedding_dim)
        self.item_embedding = nn.Embedding(num_items, embedding_dim)

    def forward(self, user_ids, item_ids):
        user_vecs = self.user_embedding(user_ids)
        item_vecs = self.item_embedding(item_ids)
        user_vecs = nn.functional.normalize(user_vecs, p=2, dim=1)
        item_vecs = nn.functional.normalize(item_vecs, p=2, dim=1)
        return user_vecs, item_vecs

class DeepModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_users, num_items, embedding_dim):
        super(DeepModel, self).__init__()
        self.user_embedding = nn.Embedding(num_users, embedding_dim)
        self.item_embedding = nn.Embedding(num_items, embedding_dim)

        self.user_embedding = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Embedding(num_users, num_users // 2, sparse=False),
            nn.Linear(num_users // 2, num_users // 4),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.LayerNorm(num_users // 4),
            nn.Linear(num_users // 4, num_users // 4),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.LayerNorm(num_users // 4),
            nn.Linear(num_users // 4, embedding_dim),
        )

        self.item_embedding = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Embedding(num_items, num_items // 2, sparse=False),
            nn.Linear(num_items // 2, num_items // 4),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.LayerNorm(num_items // 4),
            nn.Linear(num_items // 4, num_users // 4),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.LayerNorm(num_users // 4),
            nn.Linear(num_users // 4, embedding_dim),
        )

    def forward(self, user_ids, item_ids):
        user_vecs = self.user_embedding(user_ids)
        item_vecs = self.item_embedding(item_ids)
        user_vecs = nn.functional.normalize(user_vecs, p=2, dim=1)
        item_vecs = nn.functional.normalize(item_vecs, p=2, dim=1)
        return user_vecs, item_vecs

model = ShallowModel(num_users, num_items, embedding_dim)
criterion = nn.CosineEmbeddingLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

# Training loop
num_epochs = 10
batch_size = 128

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0
    for i in range(0, len(pairs), batch_size):
        batch_user = user_tensor[i:i + batch_size]
        batch_item = item_tensor[i:i + batch_size]
        batch_label = label_tensor[i:i + batch_size]

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        user_vecs, item_vecs = model(batch_user, batch_item)
        loss = criterion(user_vecs, item_vecs, batch_label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        epoch_loss += loss.item()

    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {epoch_loss / len(pairs)}")

The DeepModel gives training errors like this:
Epoch 1/10, Loss: 0.003413080421835184
Epoch 2/10, Loss: 0.0013886310887057335
Epoch 3/10, Loss: 0.0007433657232671976
Epoch 4/10, Loss: 0.0007341539347544313
Epoch 5/10, Loss: 0.0007339822536101565
Epoch 6/10, Loss: 0.0007340453288052231
Epoch 7/10, Loss: 0.0007221474995138124
Epoch 8/10, Loss: 0.0006695556226652116
Epoch 9/10, Loss: 0.0006692964146845043
Epoch 10/10, Loss: 0.0006692651472752914

While the ShallowModel gives training errors like this:
Epoch 1/10, Loss: 0.004204147369042039
Epoch 2/10, Loss: 0.002716235672868788
Epoch 3/10, Loss: 0.0007084207129199058
Epoch 4/10, Loss: 0.00012989769199339208
Epoch 5/10, Loss: 3.5592780276783744e-05
Epoch 6/10, Loss: 7.396897878606978e-06
Epoch 7/10, Loss: 1.934422210979392e-07
Epoch 8/10, Loss: -3.343448042869568e-11
Epoch 9/10, Loss: -1.2555974535644053e-10
Epoch 10/10, Loss: -1.2762611731886864e-10


i would suggest you use a residual network architecture. more layers are harder to train
